# Page Redirection after Form submit

Tags: codeigniter

ex : [www.dev.com/admin/function/234_23](http://www.dev.com/admin/function/234_23)
I has to redirect back to [www.dev.com/admin/function/234](http://www.dev.com/admin/function/234)
after id 23 edit and again submit

Comment: Hi Sasi, Thanks for posting in stack overflow . please post the question with more description and code snippet if possible

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter `$this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments())`, gets the last URI Segment `234_23`. You can then use `strstr()` to get all the text before `_` as follows

```
$oldSegment = $this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments());
$newSegment = strstr("$oldSegment", "_", true);
```

Then use `redirect()` with the `$newSegment`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('sucess_msg', 'Record Updated Sucessfully!');
redirect('user-information', 'refresh'); //user-information is route name or you can name function here as well depending upon your requirements
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I wrote in comments